# Error de sintaxis en calculo de vega en BSM model

Tags: python-3.7, scipy

No logro calcular el valor de la griega vega por que me salta error de sintaxis en la línea correspondiente a la misma y no logro identificar cual es el error. A simple vista no parece un error de indentación

```
def bsm_vega(S0, K, T, r, sigma):
    ''' Vega of European option in BSM model.
    Parameters
    ==========
    S0 : float
    initial stock/index level
    K : float
    strike price
    T : float
    maturity date (in year fractions)
    r : float
    constant risk-free short rate
    sigma : float
    volatility factor in diffusion term
    Returns
    =======
    vega : float
    partial derivative of BSM formula with respect
    to sigma, i.e. Vega
    '''
    from math import log, sqrt
    from scipy import stats
    S0 = float(S0)
    d1 = (log(S0 / K) + (r + 0.5 * sigma ** 2) * T / (sigma * sqrt(T))
    vega = S0 * stats.norm.cdf(d1, 0.0, 1.0) * sqrt(T)
    return vega
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te falta un cierra paréntesis en esta línea:

```
   d1 = (log(S0 / K) + (r + 0.5 * sigma ** 2) * T / (sigma * sqrt(T)))
```

Cuando te aparezca esos errores, siempre revisa la línea anterior.